# Translating Ramban on Dovid Hamelech's birth/ancestry

Tags: tanach, translation, ramban

I am trying to learn this with a friend but I am having trouble translating - any help would be great! Does anyone know according to Ramban  what is the miracle involved in the birth of Dovid Hamelech/his ancestry?

> והנה אתן לך עד נאמן על מה שאמרתי ידענו כי מעת בוא ישראל לארץ עד לדת אדונינו דוד היה כשלש מאות ושבעים שנה והימים יתחלקו לארבעה דורות שלמון ובועז ועובד וישי ויגיע לכל אחד מהם צ"ג שנה והנה כלם זקנים קרוב לאברהם והיו מולידים כל אחד בשנת מותו שלא כדרך כל הארץ כי אין החיים בזמנם מאה שנה ואם הוליד אחד מהם בבחרותו כמנהג יהיו האחרים זקנים מאד יותר מאברהם ויהי בהם הפלא גדול יותר מאד כי ימי האדם בדור אברהם ארוכים ובשנות דוד חזרו למחציתם ואולי חיו יותר כי אפשר שהיו לשלמון ימים רבים בבואם לארץ ולכן נתנו אנשי הקבלה והם חכמי אמת לעובד ימים רבים והוא נס נסתר נעשה לאבי המלוכה בן הצדקת הבאה לחסות תחת כנפי השכינה וכן יזכירו באמו ארך ימים רבים

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. You can improve the chances of someone being able to answer your question by [edit]ing your post to provide the citation for the Ramban.

Answer (score 3):

It's a question of arithmetic.

Ramban assumes that David was born approximately 370 years after Bnei Yisrael entered the Land. But only four generations spanned that time: Salmon (who was the son of Nachshon ben Aminadav and was one of those who entered the land), Boaz, Oved and Yishai. (See Rut 4:18-22.)

This means that each generation spanned an average of 370/4 = 93 years i.e. each of them fathered a child at 93 (assuming Salmon entered the land as an infant; otherwise this number only increases). You could argue, says Ramban, that some of them may have fathered their child at a younger age, but then that just means that the others would have had to father children at an even older age.

This is an even greater miracle than in the days of Avraham, because at this time people were not living extended lifetimes (unlike Avraham who, although he fathered a child at 100, lived until 180).

Because of these calculations, Ramban says, Chazal believed that Oved (son of Rut and David's grandfather) had an unusually long lifetime, fathering Yishai towards the end of his very long life.